# failing to attach eBPF `kretprobes` to `napi_poll()` with bcc tools

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

Idea is to use `argdist` to measure latency duration of `napi_poll()` which returns number of packet processed (called work). Ratio of execution latency of `napi_poll()` to number of packets processed would give me average amount of time it took to process each packet in form of histogram.

I am using following command

`argdist -H 'r:c:napi_poll():u64:$latency/$retval#avg time per packet (ns)'`

which end up giving me error `Failed to attach BPF to kprobe` and in dmesg I get message like `Could not insert probe at napi_poll+0: -2`

I am just curios why I can not attach `kretprobes` to `napi_poll()` when similar trick works with `net_rx_action()` ?

Comment: Could you try with a simpler tool? For example, `funccount napi_poll`. On my system, `napi_poll` doesn't work but `net_rx_action` does. Probably just because one is inlined and not the other.

Comment: I think you are right about inlined-ness of function as I tried every other way and napi_poll never worked.

Comment: I'll write a full answer with suggestions, but unfortunately, there isn't much you can do if you can't intercept the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time the `Failed to attach BPF to kprobe` error is caused by an inlined function. As explained in the [Kprobes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) (section `Kprobes Features and Limitations`), Kprobes will fail to attach if the target function was inlined. Since [`napi_poll` is static](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.9/source/net/core/dev.c#L5524), it might have been inlined at compile time.

You can check in kernel symbols if `napi_poll` was inlined or not:

```
$ cat /boot/System.map-`uname -r` | grep " napi_poll"
$
$ cat /boot/System.map-`uname -r` | grep " net_rx_action"
ffffffff817d8110 t net_rx_action
```

On my system, `napi_poll` is inlined while `net_rx_action` is not.

---

There are several workarounds for this problem, depending on your goal.

1. If you don't mind recompiling your kernel, you can use the [Linux `inline` attribute](https://www.kernel.org/doc/local/inline.html) to ensure `napi_poll` is not inlined.
2. If you can't change your kernel, the usual workaround is to find a calling function of `napi_poll` that provides the same information. A function called by `napi_poll` can also work if it provides enough information and is not inlined itself.