# EBPF probe for compiled inlined function

Tags: go, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

Id like to create an EBPF program for Golang that records when a function is entered and returns.

Some issues I have:

- A. Functions are inlined.
- B. Closures are anonymous.
- C. Reading Golang structs.

Questions:

A.

In my case its not possible to prevent function inlining with `go build -gcflags '-l`.

If I could identify the instruction of the inlined function in the binary could I place a probe on it (instead of "place probe on function X" can I tell EBPF to "place probe at instruction X"?).

B.

Can I do the same with anonymous closures?

C.

How do I read Golang structs in an EBPF C program?

I want to extract scalar values that belong to a struct hierarchy. The examples I can find all probe functions that take scalars not structs as their args.

**Related**

- [failing to attach eBPF `kretprobes` to `napi_poll()` with bcc tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963531/failing-to-attach-ebpf-kretprobes-to-napi-poll-with-bcc-tools)
- http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-01-31/golang-bcc-bpf-function-tracing.html

Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: These questions are tightly coupled, it would not make sense to separate them as if you are asking one of them its likely you will need the others.